# NSTextField add line spacing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, nsattributedstring

I use NSTextField not NSTextView to receive the user input, but I need to custom the font and textColor and line spacing. I use the code below, it's ok for font and color but I don't know how to set a line spacing.

```
[self.titleField setTextColor:textColor];
[self.titleField setFont:bold14];
```

And I also use a NSAttributedString to solve the problem:

```
NSFont *bold14 = [NSFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
NSColor *textColor = [NSColor redColor];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *textParagraph = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[textParagraph setLineSpacing:10.0];

NSDictionary *attrDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:bold14, NSFontAttributeName, textColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, textParagraph, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];
NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:attrDic]; 
[self.titleField setAllowsEditingTextAttributes:YES];
[self.titleField setAttributedStringValue:attrString];
```

the code above is ok to show a attributed string, but when I delete the string in the textfield and start to input, the words come without any attribute.

How can I input a string in NSTextField with custom font, color and line spacing?

Answer (score 4):

It's best to stay with `NSTextField's` attribute setting methods instead of an `NSAttributedString` because then it can send the settings to the field editor. Every text field has an `NSTextView` (most of the time) "[Field Editor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/FieldEditor.html)"; and the field editor is what is doing the editing.

Your `NSAttributedString` isn't sticking because you're only telling the textfield to temporarily display that one string. When the field editor pops up the text field (cell) passes on its own attributes like `textField.font` and `textField.textColor` but never the `NSAttributedString`'s attributes.

It would be best to use an `NSTextView` to be able to use `-setDefaultParagraphStyle` because you're editing multiple lines anyways, from what I see. If you can't, because of performance problems or something else, then:

---

Subclass `NSTextFieldCell`, because that's what does all the `NSTextField` work, and override

```
- (NSText *)setUpFieldEditorAttributes:(NSText *)textObj
```

(declared in `NSCell`) to set up attributes for your field editor the way you want it, so you can send it a line height value through `-setDefaultParagraphStyle` (and font etc.) yourself. (`textObj` is the field editor to be set up).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't find the setDefaultParagraphStyle method in the NSText reference

Comment: That is because the field editor is really an `NSTextView` despite the return type of `setUpFieldEditorAttributes:` being `NSText`.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but that still does not work (in Swift). I am casting the textObj to NSTextView, setting the defaultParagraphStyle and returning it. With no avail. The text jumps up when selecting it.